# Find 'M' and multiply number by 1 million then find 'B' and multiply number by 1 billion

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am downloading financial data and I have a few columns with data points that look like this:

```
34.60B
18.66M
```

This occurs in column number 6, which has a header of 'Market Cap'.  It also occurs in column number 41, which has a header named 'Avg Volume'.  How can I find the cells with an 'M' and multiply these values by a million, and likewise, find the cells with a 'B' and multiply these values by a billion, and finally multiply values with 'K' by a thousand?  I'm trying to convert everything to numeric so I don't have text and number mixed together.

Here is a sample of the data that I am referring to:

```
                                 Industry Country Market Cap     P/E    PEG
0         Medical Laboratories & Research     USA     22.29B   19.94   1.88   
1                                Aluminum     USA      4.07B    0.00   0.00   
2                    Exchange Traded Fund     USA          0    0.00   0.00   
3                        Asset Management     USA     34.60B    0.00   0.00   
4             Specialized Health Services     USA     18.66M    0.00   0.00   
5                    Exchange Traded Fund     USA          0    0.00   0.00   
6                          Major Airlines     USA     14.96B   10.83   0.75
```

Here is the code that I'm using.

```
import pandas  as pd
from pandas import read_csv
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
# load data

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\path_here\\stocks.csv')
print(df)

for index, row in df.head(n=2).iterrows():
     print(index, row)
```

Comment: Can you provide a more complete representation of your input text, along with expected output? Please cover all possible edge cases that might arise. Posting your attempt as an [mcve] is also great, if possible. Thanks.

Comment: How is the data stored in python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must iterate over the values as strings, since the letters prevent conversion to numeric types. Then you can trim and scale like this:

```
if value.endswith("M"):
    value = float(value[:-1]) * 10**6
elif value.endswith("B"):
    value = float(value[:-1]) * 10**9
else:
    value = float(value)
```

Since you are using pandas, the simplest way to apply this to a column is to wrap it in a function and use, ehm, `apply`:

```
def convert_scale(value):
    if value.endswith("M"):
        return float(value[:-1]) * 10**6
    elif value.endswith("B"):
        return float(value[:-1]) * 10**9
    else:
        return float(value)

df["PEG"] = df["PEG"].apply(convert_scale)
df["Avg Volume"] = df["Avg Volume"].apply(convert_scale)
```

Comment: If the data is stored in a pandas dataframe then just make this a function and use the pandas `apply()` to apply the function to the columns

Comment: You don't need to slice string. See my answer :)

Comment: Alexis, I just posted a small piece of code that I'm using to read the CSV data.  I can easily iterate through rows of data in the dataframe, but I can't get it to work with your code.  DO you know how to modify the code you posted to read through all the items in a dataframe?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I do. Make your loop print columns 6 and 41, and their type. Then you can replace `value` in my code with a reference to each of these columns, and you are done. (Better yet, turn it into a function. Then you could use `apply` as @noah says, or just use it to simplify your loop.)

Answer (score 0):

### **You can use string.replace**

Say you have extracted the values into strings as so:

```
strs = ['34.60B', '18.66M']
```

Then you can do

```
nums = []

for str in strs:
    rep = str.replace('B', 'e9')
    rep = rep.replace('M', 'e6')
    nums.append(float(rep))
```

Then

```
>>> nums
[34600000000.0, 18660000.0]
```

Comment: @ BlueRine, I tried that and got this:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'No.'

'No.' is the name of my very first column.  Basically, the very first cell throws and error.

Comment: @ alexis, I tried your code and got this error:
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Comment: @asher I'm starting from the strings as shown in my answer. I don't consider the columns directly and assume you already have the strings!

Comment: So both me and @alexis are assuming that your input is a string, not a dataframe or column

Comment: @asher you should be commenting on my answer under _my_ answer, not here! I don't get notified when you do that. Anyway if you don't know how to target each string in your data with the solutions given here, you should have provided the code that you are using to get at your data. We are not going to guess how you read in your data.

Comment: Thanks BlueRine S. Your specific scenario works fine, but I'm reading data from a CSV file into a dataframe.  I need to loop through all the elements of the dataframe and make the changes I described in my original post.  How can I do that?  Thanks.